# How to add a symbol to cmake, in debug mode only?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, cmake

I want the following code to only be compiled in debug mode

main.cpp

```
    #ifdef __DEBUG__
        int a=1;
        std::cout<<a;
    #endif
```

adding the following to cmake

```
add_compile_options(
  "-D__DEBUG__"
)
```

or

```
add_compile_options(
  "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-D__DEBUG__>"
)
```

just doesn't seem to do anything.

How can I achieve desired behavior?

Comment: Did you rebuild the makefiles?

Comment: The prefedined debug config is named `Debug` so does `add_compile_options( "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-D__DEBUG__>")` work? There is also an `add_compile_definitions` command that can be used without the `-D` prefix: `add_compile_definitions($<$<CONFIG:Debug>:__DEBUG__>)`

Comment: `add_compile_definitions($<$<CONFIG:Debug>:__DEBUG__>)` combined with `#if defined(__DEBUG__)` worked. Thanks :)

Comment: **Quit using and recommending directory commands in CMake!!** They will lead you down a road to absolute madness. Use `target_compile_definitions` instead of `add_compile_definitions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1: `NDEBUG`

CMake *already* defines `NDEBUG` during release builds, just use that:

```
    #ifndef NDEBUG
        int a=1;
        std::cout<<a;
    #endif
```

### Option 2: `target_compile_definitions`

The configuration is spelled `Debug`, not `DEBUG`. Since you should *never, **ever*** use directory-level commands (like `add_compile_options`), I'll show you how to use the target-level command instead:

```
target_compile_definitions(
  myTarget PRIVATE "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:__DEBUG__>"
)
```

There's no need to use the overly generic compile *options* commands, either. CMake already provides an abstraction for making sure that preprocessor *definitions* are available.

Comment: 1. the double negation really makes little sense to me, but nice to know it exists. 2. "you should never ever use..." - why?

Comment: @Gulzar (1), `NDEBUG` is a standard symbol defined by C for disabling the `assert()` macro, so it's fairly unsurprising to use in this way. (2) the directory level commands in CMake have highly confusing and non-local behavior. For instance, they apply to _all_ targets in the same directory (even those that were defined before the call) and those in subdirectories that were included _after_ the call, but not subdirectories that were included _before_ the call. They're a relic from the 2.x days that should simply be forgotten.

Comment: Here's a direct quote from the book "Professional CMake" by Craig Scott, one of the CMake maintainers: "The reader should expect to encounter plenty of examples
and tutorials online and elsewhere which still recommend patterns and approaches employing the
older methods using variables and directory property commands. It should be understood that the
target_…() commands should be the preferred approach in the CMake 3.0+ era."

Answer (score 0):

Try setting CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-D__DEBUG__")
```

In source code

```
#if defined(__DEBUG__)
 int a=1;
 std::cout<<a;
#endif
```

Comment: That wouldn't add this exclusively for the Debug configuration.